# how do the debug in SharePoint in script editor where we write javascript?

Tags: javascript, debugging, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I am coding something in Web part in SharePoint 2013 in javascript and I need to debug.How can I do it? With that If I  am trying to debug it from  inspect element debugger mode ,I am not getting the output in debug mode.How can I debug the script in web part.

Any alternative method where SharePoint environment like  client side is created and then i write it and get excute and copy it to web part.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `debugger;` anywhere in your code. This has the same function as a breakpoint if a debugging tool is opened.

In the following example, the `console.log` statement will not have been executed yet.

```
var sum = 1 + 2;
debugger;
console.log(sum);
```